# Injective immersion (between smooth manifolds) that is no homeomorphism onto its image

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Is there an injective immersion between smooth manifolds that is no homeomorphism onto its image? With smooth I mean $C^\infty$-manifolds and of course also the immersion should be $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an injective immersion of $\mathbb{R}$ into the plane, whose image is the figure 8. Clearly it it not an homeomorphism to its image (since this is not a manifold).

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersed_submanifold#Immersed_submanifolds

Comment: Thanks. That was easy. I wonder why I didn't figure that out by myself.

Comment: Often counterexamples are easy once you "see" it. Coming up with them in the first place is the hard part. The counterexample I stated is the standard one.

Comment: But sometimes it's hard to verify that your example is really a counterexample. But of course not in that case.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain and Thomas Rot, wait this is homeomorphism not diffeomorphism? I believe this is a counterexample to "a smooth injective immersion is also a smooth embedding", but I don't see how this is a counterexample to "a smooth injective immersion is also a topological embedding"...directly. Of course indirectly it follows by either [your definition of smooth embedding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0tQh.png) or an equivalent definition of [your definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJc2M.png)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain and Thomas Rot, In other words, you're showing this is injective immersion is not a smooth embedding and thus not a topological embedding. How do you show directly that this injective immersion is not a topological embedding? (By the way I'm aware that right after [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0tQh.png) is an example with Figure 8)

Comment: @SeleneAuckland: Study the preimage of small connected open sets around the cross. You can choose connected ones. However the preimage of this connected set is not connected, it contains three opens.

Comment: @ThomasRot [Example 5.4b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deZa4.png). What of it? My point is that I think you are showing a counterexample to disprove diffeomorphism and not (directly) homeomorphism.

Comment: @ThomasRot Oh you mean the cross is like the Figure 8?

Comment: The cross is ( up to homeomorphism ) contained in the figure 8. The space is not locally euclidean there

Comment: Are manifold structures preserved under homeomorphisms like if $f: A \to B$ is a homeomorphism between topological spaces $A$ and $B$ and $A$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, then $B$ is also? I think this would explain your answer without further comments. I mean, I already knew cross and figure 8 were not manifolds. Also, I think your last comment addresses only my last comment and not my comment before that.

Comment: Being a topological manifold is a topological property and preserved under homeomorphisms. Being a smooth manifold is not ( milnor showed that there are distinct smooth manifolds that are homeomorphic to the seven sphere)

Comment: @ThomasRot Thanks. Actually I wasn't notified since I wasn't tagged. Anyway, rereading our discussion from a month ago, by "since this is not a manifold" did you mean "since this is not a topological manifold" ? It seems that I thought I understood it as "smooth manifold" (I don't remember what I thinking anymore, haha). Of course not topological implies not smooth, but I think pointing out it's not smooth is not directly relevant. Pointing out it's not topological is directly relevant and answers the question, I believe.